# show data from another model in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this model `

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CopiesNum { get; set; }
    public int CurrentCopiesNum { get; set; )
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
```

i want throug this action to show up the name of author which i made it to search `

```
 public ActionResult SearchForBook(string BookName)
    {
        var book1 = from s in db.Books
                     select s;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookName))
        {
            book1 = book1.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(BookName));
        }
        ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorId", "Name").ToList();
        // var book = db.Books.Include(b => b.author).ToList();
        return View(book1);
    }
```

when i try to show the name of author

```
                     <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.author.Name)
                    </td>
```

it shows nothing

Comment: what error are you getting when using .Include ?

Comment: no error but it still does not work

Comment: are you have authors of the book name? place a breakpoint and check does author of any book is present?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Eager loading, you need to include `Author`. Try something like this:

In your Controller-

```
 var book1 = db.Books.Include(a => a.Author).ToList();
```

If you want to use lazy loading then in the model

```
public virtual Author author { get; set; }
```

Then your controller should work.

**Modification**

As you said about your requirement in the comment section, this can also be achieved like below:
In you Controller:

```
 var book1 = new Book();
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookName))
    {
        book1 = _context.Books.Include(c => c.Author).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Title == "BookName");
    }
```

You can simply send book1 to the `view` (You should check if book1 contains anything and if not then handle it properly).

And if you really don't want to change the way you coded, you can edit the Controller like below:

```
var book1 = from s in _context.Books.Include(c => c.Author)
                    select s;
```

And keep the rest of the code as it is. It should also work (though I do not recommend this.)

Comment: it didn't work and it makes an error because I have used in the query

Comment: What is the error you are having? Did you tried Eager Loading as I suggested?

Comment: You are putting the code in wrong place. 
In your controller replace `var book1 = from s in db.Books
                     select s;` with `var book1 = db.Books.Include(a => a.Author).ToList();`

Comment: so you changed the purpose of my action 
why should i do that ?
i need to search for a book and show its author

Comment: How did it change the purpose of your action?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should also do. In your code `var book1 = from s in db.Books select s;` you are getting all the books from your db and then  getting the information of the specific book you are searching. Basically `var book1 = from s in db.Books select s;` and  `var book1 = db.Books.Include(a => a.Author).ToList();` are doing the same thing here except my code will also fetch the associated Author information with books. I can give you a better approach though.

Comment: when I replaced it as you said it does not recognize (book1.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(BookName));) and shows error

Comment: what about your approach sir can you tell me please

Comment: You are fetching all the books from the db, then iterating over it to search the required book. You can just use `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookName))
        {
            book1 = db.Books.Include(a => a.Author).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Title == "BookName");
        }` and return book1 to the view.

Comment: "when I replaced it as you said it does not recognize (book1.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(BookName));) and shows error"

In that case change `c => c.Title.Contains(BookName)` to `c => c.Title == "BookName"`

Comment: @AymanSafi please check the modified answer and let me know if your issue is solved.

Comment: ((The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'library_beta.Models.Book', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[library_beta.Models.Book]')).

Comment: What are you receiving in the View? Book or Ienumerable<Book>? Show me what you did (the full code including the View). show me the error code if you can.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<library_beta.Models.Book>

Comment: as you said "i need to search for a book and show its author" then why would you send a list in the view?

Comment: If you want to send a list then change `SingleOrDefault` to `FindAll`